# How to use startup class inside program file on .NET 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I working on an ASP.NET Core 2.2 web application. I have some issues when upgrade my application to .NET 6.

My issue is that there's no `startup` class in .NET 6.0 and I found `program.cs` file only.

I add startup class on my web application but I don't know how to use it inside `Program.cs`.

How to add or use `startup` class inside my `program.cs`?

This is the `startup.cs` file in .NET Core 2.2:

```
public class Startup
{
        private readonly IConfigurationRoot configRoot;
        private AppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).CreateLogger();
            Configuration = configuration;

            IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            configRoot = builder.Build();

            AppSettings = new AppSettings();
            Configuration.Bind(AppSettings);
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddController();
            services.AddDbContext(Configuration, configRoot);
            services.AddIdentityService(Configuration);

            services.AddAutoMapper();

            services.AddScopedServices();
            services.AddTransientServices();

            services.AddSwaggerOpenAPI();
            services.AddMailSetting(Configuration);
            services.AddServiceLayer();
            services.AddVersion();

            services.AddHealthCheck(AppSettings, Configuration);
            services.AddFeatureManagement();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory log)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors(options =>
                 options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                 .AllowAnyHeader()
                 .AllowAnyMethod());

            app.ConfigureCustomExceptionMiddleware();

            log.AddSerilog();

            //app.ConfigureHealthCheck();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.ConfigureSwagger();

            app.UseHealthChecks("/healthz", new HealthCheckOptions
            {
                Predicate = _ => true,
                ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse,
                ResultStatusCodes =
                {
                    [HealthStatus.Healthy] = StatusCodes.Status200OK,
                    [HealthStatus.Degraded] = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                    [HealthStatus.Unhealthy] = StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable,
                },
            }).UseHealthChecksUI(setup =>
              {
                  setup.ApiPath = "/healthcheck";
                  setup.UIPath = "/healthcheck-ui";
                  //setup.AddCustomStylesheet("Customization/custom.css");
              });

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
}
```

And this is my .NET 6 `program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

How to use the `startup` class inside `program.cs` class ?

**Updated Post**
every thing is working but configure service not working
because i don't know how to implement `ILoggerFactory`
on `startup`

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory log)
        {
        }
```

on program.cs

```
startup.Configure(app, app.Environment,???);
```

How to add logger factory as third paramter on `program.cs`
`ILoggerFactory` is buit in class
**Updated** it solved using

```
var app = builder.Build();
startup.Configure(
    app,
    builder.Environment,
    app.Services.GetRequiredService<FooService>(),
    app.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>()
);
```

can you please tell me how to apply swagger ui to check my api

Comment: See [this migration guide by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) which explains how to deal with the changes between earlier .NET Core versions, and .NET 6, when it comes to the startup of your app

Comment: i make it but remining call configure function on startup class

Comment: Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory log) on startup when calling on program configure give exceptionvar startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration);
startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);
var app = builder.Build();
startup.Configure(app, app.Environment);

Comment: This c# corner might help https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-add-startup-cs-class-in-asp-net-core-6-project/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New templates use the so called [minimal hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#nhm) but nobody prevents from switching back to the [generic hosting one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-7.0) used previously (or via [`WebHost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-7.0)).

If you want to work with [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements) you can copy contents of `Main` method to the `Program.cs` file and then copy all other methods declared in the old `Program` class. New `Program.cs` potentially can look something like this:

```cs
await CreateHostBuilder(args)
    .Build()
    .RunAsync();

// do not forget to copy the rest of the setup if any
static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Or just remove the `Startup` class completely and move configure methods to corresponding parts of new file (maybe extracting some to concise extension methods).

Answer (score 8):

You can manually instantiate the `Startup` and manually call the method `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` :

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration);
startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

var app = builder.Build();
startup.Configure(app, builder.Environment);
```

In ASP.NET Core 2.*, `Startup.Configure` accepted injected service :

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddSingleton<IFooService, FooService>();
    }

    public void Configure(WebApplication app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IFooService fooService, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

       fooService.Init();
       ...
    }
}
```

Then you can :

```cs
var app = builder.Build();
startup.Configure(
    app,
    builder.Environment,
    app.Services.GetRequiredService<FooService>(),
    app.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>()
);
```

---

When I migrated my APIs, first I consider to reuse the `Startup` class... but finally I moved the configuration in extension methods.

Comment: yes good but  i face issue i can't pass logging to configure startup.Configure(app, builder.Environment);Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory log)

Comment: how to pass illoger factory as thid paramter to startup.configure

Comment: @ahmedbarbary - `ILoggerFactory` is a service. You can pass like `FooService` in the example.

Comment: this interface ILoggerFactory log is built in how to pass it please

Comment: @ahmedbarbary - I updated the example to include `ILoggerFactory `.

Comment: yes it working but remaining three app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run(); where i use that on configure or where is place i put it

Comment: Or just switch back to the generic hosting model =)

Comment: This worked great for me in a normal web application, but I am having trouble now trying to use this startup class with my tests using WebApplicationFactory in .NET 7.0.  I have a custom WebApplicationFactory and I can't understand what I need to write / override to be able to use Startup as suggested here. Can anyone please help?

Comment: @killswitch, In derived `WebApplicationFactory`, I only override [ConfigureWebHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1.configurewebhost). If you need more detail, can you open a question?

Comment: @vernou I just posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77408751/webapplicationfactory-how-to-use-net-6-0-webapplication-createbuilder-instead