# How to programmatically launch a .NET 6 minimal API with no Startup class

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, pact, pact-net

I am trying to implement PactNet contract tests on our provider project. However the issue is that we are using a Minimal API so instead of having a Startup.cs and Program.cs class we just have it all rolled into one Program.cs.

This poses an issue, as previously I would have been able to run `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` and pass it the `Startup` class, as demonstrated in the [PactNet](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net) samples. All the examples of doing something similar that I've run across on SO use `TestServer` or `WebApplicationFactory`, which are inapplicable in this scenario since they start an in-memory server, and I need a server running on a real TCP socket, so that PactNets Rust internals can communicate with it.

The only solution I've managed to find is to just manually run the provider with `dotnet run` however this feels hackish, and I would much prefer to do it programmatically as previously was possible with `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

Things you can try:

- Switching back to the generic hosting (see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74512655/2501279)).
- Switching from top-level statements to "standard" `Main` entrypoint - declare a class with static `Main` method and move everything into it (for example in the same `Program.cs` file) and call this `Program.Main` instead of old setup (note that this will greatly reduce customizability of the starting server):

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // ... everything from your Program.cs
    }
}
```

- Extracting parts of the top-level statements file into methods and calling them on manually created builder (almost the same as keeping `Startup` file and calling it's methods on appropriate parts of builder and app in the new setup).