# WebApplicationFactory: How to use .NET 6.0 WebApplication.CreateBuilder instead of older Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()?

Tags: c#, .net-core, web-applications, .net-7.0, minimal-apis

I have successfully converted my web applications to start using the new WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args) method, but I am not managing to replicate this success in my tests using a custom (derived) WebApplicationFactory.

I decided to keep a loose concept of a Startup class in my codebase (due to inheritance and what not), but I now call it manually as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/74506909/5044734.

My code used to work like this:

```
public class TestWebApiFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup>
    where TStartup : class
{
    public TestWebApiFactory()
    {
    }

    protected override void ConfigureClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        base.ConfigureClient(client);
    }

    protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                        {
                            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");                                    
                        })
                      .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(x =>
                      {
                          x.UseStartup<TStartup>().UseTestServer();
                      });
        return builder;
    }       
}
```

How do I achieve the same thing using the WebApplication model instead?

Comment: Just use the standard integration testing approach for minimal hosting model (do not confuse it with Minimal APIs - it is another concept) - for example as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70093628/integration-test-and-hosting-asp-net-core-6-0-without-startup-class/70095604#70095604). `Startup` in the new (minimal) hosting model is just an POCO class with no special meaning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integration test and hosting ASP.NET Core 6.0 without Startup class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70093628/integration-test-and-hosting-asp-net-core-6-0-without-startup-class)

Comment: Thanks @GuruStron, I did come across that link, but what I'm trying to understand is how can I create tests which call different WebApplicationFactory instances which each take a different TEntryPoint using this approach.  I cannot create multiple "Program" classes due to the following error:  "CS8802: Only one compilation unit can have top-level statements."

This used to be easy before; all you had to do is use a different startup class as an entry point.

Comment: Why do you have multiple `Startup` classes at all (that is a bit pointless in the minimal hosting model)? How `Program` will select correct startup class to use? Use the same mechanism to make the  `WebApplicationFactory`'s (I assume something with configuration).

Comment: Also note that there is no need to migrate to the "new" minimal hosting model. You can keep the "old" generic one.

Comment: I figured I'd use multiple preset Startup classes instead of using the .WithWebHostBuilder method calls.  I've now started using that method instead, and that solved it, so thanks!  Now I have a new problem though, I am getting a "BadRequest" response on any request I send to a test controller I have in the test project.  I am calling CreateClient() and then sending a request.  What am I missing now?

Comment: Without full repro it is hard to tell. Can you post a [mre] somewhere (like github)?

Comment: I don't understand why you try to accomplish. I suggest you add in the question a test that use `TestWebApiFactory` as desired.

Comment: I found out that the "BadRequest" response is happening whenever I add the [ApiController] attribute to my controller. I am trying really hard to reproduce this behaviour in a new simple test project, but to no avail.  There is something in my production code which is causing this, but can't for the life of me figure it out. (Note: This used to work without any issue before I switched to the minimal hosting model)